# Spark logistic regression lasso running very slow

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, logistic-regression, lasso-regression

Am running a Spark Logistic Regression with Lasso and it is taking 20-30 minutes to run. Is it because of solver?

Ran it without  lasso and it took 2-4 minutes. Also a generic logistic regression took 2-4 minutes.

The data has around couple of million rows and 20-30 columns.

May be this is a bad optimizer that is used? The same problem in R/Scikit was quicker I assume.

```py
RegParam=.0115
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
lr = LogisticRegression(maxIter=1000,fitIntercept=True)
lr.setStandardization(True)
lr.setRegParam(RegParam)
lr.setTol(tolerance)
lr.setElasticNetParam(1.0)
lrModel = lr.fit(df)
```